# Convert statement from Numpy to Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, translate

I'm translating a Python class to Matlab. Most of it is straightforward, but I'm not so good with Python syntax (I hardly ever use it). I'm stuck on the following:

```
# find the basis that will be uncorrelated using the covariance matrix
basis = (sqrt(eigenvalues)[newaxis,:] * eigenvectors).transpose()
```

Can someone help me figure out what the equivalent Matlab syntax would be?

I've found via Google that `np.newaxis` increases the dimensionality of the array, and `transpose` is pretty self explanatory. So for `newaxis`, something involving `cat` in matlab would probably do it, but I'm really not clear on how Python handles arrays TBH.

Comment: Not a Python person, so I'm not posting a answer, but this looks like "sqrt(eigenvalues)[newaxis,:]" would go to something like "diag(eigenvalues)" converting a vector to a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `eigenvalues` is a 1D array of length N in Python, then `sqrt(eigenvalues)[newaxis,:]` would be a 1xN array. This is translated to MATLAB as either `sqrt(eigenvalues)` or `sqrt(eigenvalues).'`, depending on the orientation of the `eigenvalues` array in MATLAB.

The `*` operation then does broadcasting (in MATLAB this is called singleton expansion). It looks like the operation multiplies each eigenvector by the square root of the corresponding eigenvalue (assuming eigenvectors are the columns).

If in MATLAB you computed the eigendecomposition like this:

```matlab
[eigenvectors, eigenvalues] = eig(A);
```

then you’d just do:

```matlab
basis = sqrt(eigenvalues) * eigenvectors.';
```

or

```matlab
basis = (eigenvectors * sqrt(eigenvalues)).';
```

(note the parentheses) because `eigenvalues` is a diagonal matrix.